# Doing things "out of vanity"

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax

How can I say "he did it out of vanity" in Latin?
The only thing I could see is a causal ablative: *vanitate sua ita fecit*.
Are there other options for doing something "out of vanity", "out of pity", or out of any other such thing?
Or is the ablative (essentially) the only possibility?
I am not sure if the direct translation *e vanitate* is possible.

Please note that this question is about structures, not specific words, but in case it matters, the key example is "out of vanity".

Comment: How do you call this construction (out of XX) in linguistics?

Comment: @Pablo I don't know. Perhaps the linguistics site can help more than the Latin site. I'm not sure there is a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best equivalent that comes to my mind is **gen. + causā**. In this case, I would translate "out of vanity" as **vanitatis causā**.

I found no classical examples of this exact phrase, but a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22vanitatis+causa%22) reveals more than a few later examples, e.g.:

> Hic ego, Rex Serenissime, res nostras non amplifico, nec **vanitatis causa** ostento, id quod est, nudis verbis expono. (*[Apologeticus pro Societate Iesu](https://books.google.com/books?id=xyFlAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22vanitatis+causa%22&source=bl&ots=1vGU1CX0Dj&sig=yTAnBPUtvmmQtBAxRrPfyu7YBSE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW-OTq6J3YAhUBMyYKHTm5AbwQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22vanitatis%20causa%22&f=false)*)

Interestingly, Ezra Pound wrote a letter to James Joyce *in English* and used this phrase as a Latin "flourish":

> I once did a bad translation of Guido Cavalcanti of which I have a spare copy,
>    it has the text with it and that might entertain you if you're not fed up with the period, or a Corbiere...or a stray leaf of my own earlier imbecilities,
>    **vanitatis causa**. ([*Letters of Ezra Pound and James Joyce*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GZMNYLgd5X4C&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=%22vanitatis+causa%22&source=bl&ots=LPMHrZ05bi&sig=J8fi5KaXdsk7CN6sbTC6cMsbeE8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW-OTq6J3YAhUBMyYKHTm5AbwQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22vanitatis%20causa%22&f=false))

Your other example, "out of pity," could similarly be translated by **misericordiae causā**, and this time there *are* classical examples of this usage:

- Cicero:

  > Sed haec nescio quo modo frequenter in me congessisti    saneque in eo creber fuisti, te idcirco in ludos causam conicere noluisse ne ego mea consuetudine aliquid de tensis **misericordiae causa** dicerem, quod in aliis aedilibus ante fecissem. (Cicero, *Pro Plancio* 83)
- *Digesta Iustiniani*:

  > Si quis ab alio acceperit pecuniam ne mihi negotium faciat, si quidem mandatu meo datum est, uel a procuratore meo mnium rerum, uel ab eo qui negotium meum gerere uolebat et ratum habui: ego dedisse intellegor. si autem non mandatu meo alius ei licet **misericordiae causa** dederit ne fiat neque ratum habui, tunc et ipsum repetere et me in quadruplum agere posse. (Iustinianus, *Digesta Iustiniani* 3.6.7)